# TooManyActualInvocations Mockito Exceptiom

Tags: mocking, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to mock static function as shown below but I am getting TooManyActualInvocationError

```
mockStatic(FunctionService.class);

when(FunctionService.onRegion(region)).thenReturn(execution);
when(FunctionService.onRegion(region).withArgs(req)).thenReturn(execution);

verifyStatic();
FunctionService.onRegion(region).withArgs(req);
```

I also changed the verify part as below but

```
verifyStatic(); 
FunctionService.onRegion(region);
verifyStatic();
FunctionService.onRegion(region).withArgs(req);
```

and

```
verifyStatic(); 
FunctionService.onRegion(region);
verify(FunctionService.onRegion(region)).withArgs(req);
```

for both changes above getting same error

also tried

```
verifyStatic(times(1));
FunctionService.onRegion(region).withArgs(req);
```

and

```
verifyStatic(times(2));
FunctionService.onRegion(region).withArgs(req);
```

for 1 I am getting same error and for 2 I am getting nullpointerexception. Not sure what other options I have to do this correctly. I am new to mocking, mockito and power mockito

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution it works

```
verifyStatic(times(2));
FunctionService.onRegion(region);
```